# DataTables Server Side Processing from Query/View not Single Table

Tags: view, datatables, server-side

I am using the DataTables jQuery plugin to display data from a query that performs several calculations involving joins and subqueries.  I have it working fine using client side processing, with the data coming from sAjaxSource.  I would like to implement server side processing - but am not sure the most appropriate way to do this since my data is not coming from a single table.

A basic example of server side processing can be found at http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

What is the best way to address this?  If only it were as simple as using a view here...

```
/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "ajax";
```

changed to

```
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "myView";
```

Also I would prefer to implement this using PDO rather than the basic mysql_query, etc.. - but any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To implement server side processing you must simply write some code that returns a json object with the data structure explained in this [page](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side). That's it. I've don it in node.js and PHP but you na use whatever you want.
You can use whatever you want to achieve this, remember that you must take into account pagination ( so a LIMIT clause to the query ), column ordering ( ORDER BY clause ) and filtering ( WHERE clause ) and you must understand how datatables passes data that you can use to build the query.

Comment: Indeed - I realized this was the case after I took some more time to take a closer look at what was required.  The part I don't like is that I am concatenating input from an external source in my query - making it vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @MaxPowers Of course usual care should be taken to avoid that, i think that allan wanted to show a quick example on how it could be done :)